# Running lasground on input cloud produces no visible effect in lasview?

Tags: lastools

Running lasground on input cloud produces no visible effect in lasview?

It runs and writes an output file, which seems unchanged from the input file, when viewed in lasview.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You input or your commands could be wrong. You're welcome =P

Comment: @Erik I used the GUI with default settings. That is, lasground.exe under \LAStools\LAStools\bin.

Comment: @Erik It could be though that I need to use some viewer settings for seeing the results though. Maybe I'm just viewing the entire cloud, but not filtering based on the included classification IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `lasdiff` to determine the differences between your input and output file. You can also use the argument -color_by_classification (or right click in the `lasview` GUI and select it there)

[image: lasview color by...]